# Code suggestion for searching in NSStrings

Tags: objective-c

I populate my app with a plist array with dictionaries. The value for the key "Freshness" in the dictionaries is the name of a bundle image to show the level of freshness in the drink, "level1.png", "level2.png", "level3.png", "level4.png", "level5.png", "level6.png" or "level7.png".

I have added a UIStepper so the user can specify the minimum and maximum freshness of the drink like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
minImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"level1.png"];
maxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"level7.png"];
}

- (IBAction)minStepperValueChanged:(id)sender {
double stepperValue = minStepper.value;
minImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%.f.png", stepperValue]];
maxStepper.minimumValue = minStepper.value;
minStepper.maximumValue = maxStepper.value;
minLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From level %.f", stepperValue];
}

- (IBAction)maxStepperValueChanged:(id)sender {
double stepperValue = maxStepper.value;
maxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%.f.png", stepperValue]];
maxStepper.minimumValue = minStepper.value;
minStepper.maximumValue = maxStepper.value;
maxLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To level %.f", stepperValue];
}
```

When `searchButtonPressed` is called, guess what I want to happen. To add the objects with the correct level of freshness from `allObjectsArray` to `searchResultsArray`. Any suggestion for code to filter like this?

I was thinking something like using a mutable array `levelsArray` with all the level image paths, then remove the objects that goes below minimum or above maximum from `levelsArray` when `searchButtonPressed`.

Then add the dictionaries that match one of the remaining objects of this array to `searchResultsArray`. But I've twisted my brain so much on this that I really need some help. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

I've done this for a start:

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{

for(double i=otherCriteriasViewController.minStepper.value;i>1;i--) {
    [otherCriteriasViewController.levelsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%.f.png", i-1]];
}

for(double ii=otherCriteriasViewController.maxStepper.value;ii<7;ii++) {
    [otherCriteriasViewController.levelsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%.f.png", ii+1]];
}
```

and now I want to add all the objects that contain one of the objects of levelsArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, the problem you are trying to solve is filtering an array of dictionaries based on a key that is in each of the dictionaries.

You can use an `NSPredicate` to do this.

Assuming you have an NSArray called "allItems" and that each object in the array is a dictionary containing the key "Freshness".

Let's say you want all the items with a Freshness of 2.

```
NSArray *filtered = [allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Freshness == %@)", @"level2.png"]];
```

You can also do greater than and less than comparisons using NSPredicates. This is just an equals example.

Comment: I think I want something like this, thank you for answering! Can you show how to "loop through" the objects in `levelsArray` to add the drinks that contain one of these words? Check my edit.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking right now. Can you give an example case and the result you would expect to occur?

Comment: @ingenspor, I think you are misunderstanding what Dima wrote. The new array, filtered, should contain all the objects where the Freshness key equals "level2.png". There's no need to do any looping.